Shading issues along seam in 4.1 but not 3.6
I recently decided to make the move to 4.1 and imported a mesh that was created in 3.6 over to 4.1. In 3.6, it doesn't have any shading issues at all, but in 4.1, there's some really odd visuals around the seam that connects the head to the body (if this helps at all, this is a Sims 4 character that was exported and sculpted). Does anyone know the best way to fix this? It shows up in all preview and render modes. Thank you!



Is Auto Smooth enabled in 3.6? It's needed when the model has Custom Split Normals. The option has been replaced by a modifier in 4.1 (https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.1/modeling/)

@Blunder hi, I messed around with the modifer in 4.1, to no results. 3.6 doesn't have it enabled. However, I found when I did enable it in 3.6, it caused the same thing to happen that happens in 4.1. Not sure if that means anything but I figured I'd mention it!

Make sure you've got no doubled verts first off, then if that doesn't work go to the Object Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data.
